# QIODevice::read (QProcess): device not open

Tags: python, xml, qt, qt-creator, xls

I'm working on QtCreator and I want to use a python script with a xml file from QT Windows.

The file is open, but I can't use the script :

```
  QString p_stdout = _process.readAll();
```

show me : QIODevice::read (QProcess): device not open

Here is my code :

```
   // EXEC PYTHON SCRIPT


    QStringList args = (QStringList() << script_path << employesDesires << file_path) ; // parameters
    QString program = "Python";                                                         // program


    int exitCode = _process.execute( program, args );

    _process.waitForFinished(-1);

//      _process.open(QIODevice::OpenMode()) ;

    QString p_stdout = _process.readAll();

    QString s = QString::number(exitCode);

    ui->labelResult->setText(s);
```

**exitCode** return **0**

I searched on many forums but can't find a solution that I can understand..

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute), `QProcess::execute`...

> Starts the program program with the arguments arguments in a new process, waits for it to finish, and then returns the exit code of the process. Any data the new process writes to the console is forwarded to the calling process

So you never see the `QProcess` instance in an open state -- it's effectively closed by the time the call returns.

Instead, you probably want to use [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start)...

```
_process.start(program, args);
```

That will execute the specified process as a child of the caller and make its output available via the various read channels.

Also, note that while `QProcess::waitForFinished` appears to be a useful routine it's generally better to connect to the various [signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals) and react accordingly -- whether it be handling errors or reading from stdout/stderr etc.

Comment: Sorry I still do not think enough about the documentation.

So with start() function if I understand documentation, I can retrieve data from my python script, but not with execute().

I will try with your informations ! I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.  [`QProcess::execute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) is a `static` member function and acts more or less like [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system): it starts the specified program and waits for it to complete, so no information of any sort is available until it returns.  `QProcess::start`, on the other hand, simply schedules the requested process for execution and any progress/output/state change is reported via the usual `Qt` signal/slot mechanism.